# Read more to open external link

Tags: custom-field, excerpt, read-more

I would like to have custom field in post editing area where can be putted the external link.

If the link is entered to this field then read more button on homepage would open external link, but if that field is not filled then to use default read more functionality and open a post.

Is there some plugin for this or some hack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `target="_blank"` to the anchor tag.

```
function remove_more_link_scroll( $link ) {
$link = str_replace('>',' target="_blank">', $link);
return $link;
}
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'remove_more_link_scroll' );
```

I feel compelled to state that I consider forcing new tabs/windows to be very unfriendly behavior, and if you search the web you will see that I am not alone in that opinion.